# What is best practice for handling axios that sends back no request (no catch or no .then executes)?

Tags: javascript, axios

I've encountered situations where maybe because of a bad connection where there is no response from the api where it skips both the .then and .catch. What is the best practice for error handling in that case? I'd like to put up an alert if there is no response at all.

```
const getPic () => {
axios({
        url:   '/users/avatar',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        },
        data: {avatar: avatarUrl},
        responseType: 'blob',
      }).then((response) => {
        log(response);
        let blob = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
        localStorage.setItem('image', blob);

}.catch(error) {
console.log(error)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a `timeout` which will cause the promise to reject in the case that there is no response.

```
    axios({
      url:   '/users/avatar',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
      },
      timeout: 1000,
      data: {avatar: avatarUrl},
      responseType: 'blob',
    })
    ~``
```